# Can not add "boundary" to multipart/form-data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to post a multipart request to a web api. my controller looks like this:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var obj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        model,
        Formatting.None,
        new HttpPostedFileConverter());
    var boundary = "----" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
    var contentType = new StringBuilder("multipart/form-data; boundary=")
        .Append(boundary);
    var httpContent = new StringContent(
        obj,
        Encoding.UTF8,
        contentType.ToString());  //error shows here
    var uri = new StringBuilder(_domain)
        .Append("/api/email/send");
    var response = await client.PostAsync(uri.ToString(), httpContent);  
    ....  
    ....  
}
```

The problem happens when I try to add the `contentType`. It shows an error `The format of value 'multipart/form-data; boundary=---***' is invalid.`

the `model` contains data like this:
[image]

The `Attachments` type is `List<HttpPostedFileBase>`. I didn't use `MultipartFormDataContent` because I have the uploaded file right inside my model as json format, which I dont know how to use with `MultipartFormDataContent`. It would be really helpful if somebody can tell me what is wrong here, or if this isn't the right way to post then please show me an example how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will totally answer your question or not but I was dealing with this and found two means to do this...

Method one...

```
myHttpRequestMessage.Content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");                    
myHttpRequestMessage.Content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
```

Method two...

```
myHttpRequestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");
myHttpRequestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.NameValueHeaderValue("boundary", "----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"));
```

However, with that said, in my particular instance, which doesn't match yours exactly, the solution was...

```
System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent myMultipartFormDataContent = new System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent("------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
myMultipartFormDataContent.Add(new System.Net.Http.StringContent(myTextValue), "users_file", "userAccounts.csv");
myHttpRequestMessage.Content = myMultipartFormDataContent;
```